# Dart Lists - I created a list of widgets and add a widget called 'StarterDayTile' which works fine, but can't then remove in the next if statement

Tags: list, listview, flutter, dart

[image]

**I cannot remove the 'StarterDayTile' in the line that I say dayList.remove(StarterDayTile());**

This is where I originally took the screenshot from:
Apparently I have to add lots more details because my post is mostely code and I don't know what to add so I am now just writing random stuff to pass the bot who is preventing me from posting I hope this works now.

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:moody/data_screen.dart';
import 'package:moody/starter_day_tile.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';
import 'day_tile.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final String displayDate;
  final String displayEmoji;
  final int displayHapp;
  HomeScreen({this.displayHapp, this.displayDate, this.displayEmoji});

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

List<Widget> dayList = [];

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (widget.displayEmoji != null && widget.displayDate != null && widget.displayHapp != null){
      print('2');
      setState(() {
        dayList.insert(0, DayTile(date: widget.displayDate, emoji: widget.displayEmoji, happ: widget.displayHapp));
      });
    }
    if (dayList.length == 0){
      dayList.add(StarterDayTile());
    }
    else if (dayList.length == 2){
      dayList.remove(StarterDayTile());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
        onPressed: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode()); // Keyboard down
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftWithFade,
                  child: DataScreen()));
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.message),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white12,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'hero1',
          child: AppBar(
            elevation: 15,
            backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Moody',
                style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Baloo', fontSize: 35),
              ),
            ),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                bottom: Radius.circular(20),
              ),
            ),
            leading: Padding(
              child: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0, left: 10),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 0),
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.pie_chart),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        reverse: false,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: dayList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return dayList[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Is there any unique field in your StarterDayTile ?

Comment: bruh show us the whole code, please

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I am getting no error in the console. There are no unique properties in StarterDayTile. I will try to attach my code - I will add edit main post. Thanks for responding!

Comment: If there is no unique field in the class...Which particular object do you want to remove from the list?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi( I am very new programmer so I may be completely wrong here ), I am attempting to add to a ListView a list of the user's saved 'journal entries' and before they have any entries I want to have a StarterDayTile widget in it that basically just says: "Add Your first Entry!" and then it gets removed when they actually add their first entry.

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi I want to remove the StarterDayTile object (I think it's an object) after dayList.length == 2 in the initState

Comment: I get you now...You want to remove the object you added to the list initially when there are more than 1 objects in list

Comment: Am I right?????

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi yes!

Comment: Is it getting to the if statement?... I mean print something before your remove statement did you get anything?

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi Yup, it gets there. It's just the remove statement that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add the DayTile class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this; since it is the first object you want to remove

```
    dayList.removeAt(0);
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it removes the original starter message but then it also removes all the new journal entries the user adds afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!!

I made a bool called startDayTileExists and made it a global variable and then when I added the StarterDayTile to the list I made it equal true and then I changed the dayList.remove() to a dayList.removeAt(1); but made an extra requirement in the if that startDayTileExists had to equal true then in the if I removed it and made startDayTileExists equal to false again.

Thanks for all your help!